# Errors when trying to re size Images

Tags: php, image

I am trying to re size photos in a while loop in php but I keep receiving errors like:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in C:\Users\Bob\xampp\htdocs\house\allphotos.php on line 17

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'userphotos/27_1366493160164_BMW.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in C:\Users\Bob\xampp\htdocs\house\allphotos.php on line 17

Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\Bob\xampp\htdocs\house\allphotos.php on line 27
```

Then a ton of random characters...

In the following I am trying to echo out 2 photos selected with a new size.
I believe it has something to do with `$image`, am I not using the function right?

```
 ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1); //just added
 if ($getphotos->execute()){
       while ($array = $getphotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('userphotos/'.$array['photoname'].'');


          list($image_width, $image_height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('userphotos/'.$array['photoname'].'');

          $new_size = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/100));
          $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
          $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

          $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
          imagecopyresized($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
          $imagearray = imagejpeg($new_image, null);

          echo $imagearray;
          //echo '<img src="userphotos/'.$array['photoname'].'">';

       }
    } else { die('Query Error'); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GD can be unforgiving for jpegs that are a little off, while in theory the file works fine when you open it etc, you can supress the warning and let it continue on its merry way with the following:

```
ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
```

That will let the processing continue, and ignore the warning. Your image will more than likely still get processed without issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for the solution and I just added it in, as you can see in my edit, but it still didn't work. I am almost positive the errors originate from the `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg...` line. Is there some type of substitute I can use to make it work?

Comment: The only other suggestion would be to see if your host can upgrade the `jpglib` package

Comment: Turns out it had something to do with a specific photo, I deleted the photo and it worked.

Comment: ahh awesome, that's the other thing, PHP simply won't read corrupt files

Comment: Yes but I can still echo the image out in <img> tags so I don't know whats wrong with it... oh well!

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't take much for it to be 'corrupt' according to PHP, even though you can still open it. Try save the image as PNG, then re-save as JPG